# React SPA -- Route Duplication

Tags: reactjs, routes, single-page-application, react-router-dom

When I load `mysite.com` and navigate I have no problems.
as I use the `Link` or `NavLink` components from `react-router-dom` my SPA appropriately shows the corresponding paths:

```
mysite.com/login
mysite.com/registration
mysite.com/home
...
```

However, if I load from `mysite.com/home` (or any other path) - it appropriately loads the correct content for the landing route, but then I'm carrying around an extra path element and my `BrowserRouter` doesn't know how to handle it so I end up w/ my `404` page.

```
mysite.com/home/login
mysite.com/home/registration
mysite.com/home/home
...
```

Is there a way to have `BrowserRouter` enforce a `/` bast path?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your links with `/`. I think that might be your issue.

Comment: I'll accept in 9 minutes haha!

Thank you -- I did a regex find and replace to change all of my links and didn't realize I dropped the slash!

rookie move!

cheers!

Comment: Relative paths have got me more than once too!